# What is the difference between CreateThread's and CreateRemoteThread's lpParameter?

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the difference between `CreateThread`'s and `CreateRemoteThread`'s `lpParameter`? From the `CreateThread` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) and `CreateRemoteThread` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) the `lpParameter` is "a pointer to a variable to be passed to the thread function."

In regards to `CreateRemoteThread` the `lpParameter` is a pointer to a void object which makes sense. It could be some address at some place in memory.

```
HANDLE CreateRemoteThread(
      HANDLE                 hProcess,
      LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  lpThreadAttributes,
      SIZE_T                 dwStackSize,
      LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
      LPVOID                 lpParameter,
      DWORD                  dwCreationFlags,
      LPDWORD                lpThreadId
 );
```

In regards to `CreateThread` the `lpParameter` is a pointer to a "__drv_aliasesMem" LPVOID object. Why this addition of "__drv_aliasesMem"?

```
HANDLE CreateThread(
      LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES   lpThreadAttributes,
      SIZE_T                  dwStackSize,
      LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE  lpStartAddress,
      __drv_aliasesMem LPVOID lpParameter,
      DWORD                   dwCreationFlags,
      LPDWORD                 lpThreadId
);
```

Comment: no any difference. `CreateThread` call `CreateRemoteThread` or both call `CreateRemoteThreadEx` with the same *lpParameter*

Comment: `__drv_aliasesMem` does not mean anything.  The author of the article made a mistake and did not properly delete the SAL annotation.  Which was `__in_opt __deref __drv_aliasesMem`. The new docs are pretty sloppy that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *functional* difference between the two parameters.  They are just arbitrary `void*` pointers, nothing special about them.

`__drv_aliasesMem` is a [SAL annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/sal-annotations?view=vs-2019).  It informs a SAL-aware parser that the parameter references a memory address that is not leaked:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c28197?view=vs-2019

> Functions that take a pointer and alias it (thus avoiding a leak) should be annotated with `__drv_aliasesMem`. If you create a function that inserts an object into a global structure, or passes it to a system function that does that, you should add the `__drv_aliasesMem` annotation.

SAL annotations have no affect on a C or C++ compiler, as they are implemented as empty preprocessor macros.

See [Using SAL Annotations to Reduce C/C++ Code Defects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/using-sal-annotations-to-reduce-c-cpp-code-defects?view=vs-2019).